# Calcular porcentagem com dplyr::add_count

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

como seria posssível calcular porcentagens com o `dplyr::add_count()`?

Para calcular com o `dplyr::count()` é bem simples, como segue:

```
library(tidyverse)
dt <- Titanic

dt %>% 
  count(Sex, Pclass, sort = T) %>% 
  mutate(perc = n/sum(n)*100)
```

No entanto, essa opção não preserva as demais variáveis e eu gostaria de preserva-las. O `dplyr::add_count` faz isso, mas não consegui calcular as porcentagens da mesma forma como acima, pois os valores da contagem se repetem e o calculo acaba não fazendo sentido.

```
dt %>% 
  add_count(Sex, Pclass, sort = T) %>% 
  mutate(perc = n/sum(n)*100)
```

Alguém teria alguma sugestão? Tentei também com o `group_by()`, mas sem sucesso. Obrigado!

Comment: Não é reproduzível: `Error: object 'titanic' not found`.

Comment: Editei para 'Titanic', obrigado pela observação.

Answer (score 6):

Depois do código com `count`, faça um `join` para acrescentar as colunas restantes.

```
dt %>%
  count(Sex, Pclass, sort = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(perc = n/sum(n)*100) %>%
  inner_join(dt, .)
```